# ValueError: Input size must be at least 75x75; Received: input_shape=(32, 32, 3)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am trying to apply Transfer Learning in InceptionV3. The size of images which I have to input in the model is `(32*32*3)`. However, when I am trying to create the base model by setting the input size as `(32*32*3)`, it is giving the error as :

```
ValueError: Input size must be at least 75x75; Received: input_shape=(32, 32, 3)
```

Here is the line of code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
base_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (32, 32, 3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
```

Please let me know why is it happening? Do I need to resize the image if I want the model to be trained on my image dataset?

Comment: Yes, your images should be at least 75x75 so you need to resize. Which part did you stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the CNN passes through multiple Conv layers, where each reduces the width and height of the inputs, so the network requires a minimum of 75x75 to work properly. In your case, you have to upscale your input to 75x75, and there is no other way.